# remove (and count) duplicates from a list

Tags: java, collections

Is it possible to iterate between two iterators of a same list **and remove an item** within the nested iterator?

**Version 1 (does not work):**

```
var i = all.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    var a = i.next();
    var j = all.iterator();
    while (j.hasNext()) {
        var b = j.next();
        if (!a.shouldBRemoved(b)) {
            a.setDuplicates(a.getDuplicates + 1);
            // I want to remove the element on the fly 
            // because on each iteration the iterated elements will have a decreased size and will iterate faster (because of fewer elements)
            // However: this does NOT work because of ConcurrentModificationException:
            j.remove();  
        }
    }
```

}

I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, because I modify an element within the same iterator..

I can solve this issue by using another list `removableItems` and put those items in it:

**Version 2 (works):**

```
for (var a : all) {
    for (var b : all) {
        if (!a.shouldBRemoved(b)) {
            a.setDuplicates(a.getDuplicates + 1);
            // this works, 
            // however I must use an additation list to keep track of the items to be removed
            // it's also not more performant than removing the elements on the fly 
            // because on each iteration the iterated elements has the same size
            removableItems.add(b);
        }
    }
}
all.removeAll(removableItems);
```

**Is there a way to solve this **without** needing an intermediate list `removableItems`?** I want to remove the element on the fly.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: None of the code snippets proves the need for the nested loop/iteration.  If method `a.shouldBeRemoved` is called only on `a` without using/passing `b`, it is possible ti remove it from the outer iterator.

Comment: @AlexRudenko good point. I did forget to pass `b` into `a.shouldBeRemoved()`. I edited the code above.

Comment: You should also be checking for equality `a == b` when iterating using nested iterators.  Can you clarify which items should be removed (duplicates?) and which values should remain in `all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution so far (**Version 3**):

```
List<Item> removeDuplicates(List<Item> all) {
        var uniqueResults = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (var a : all) {
            for (var b : all) {
                // check if "a" and "b" is not the same instance, but have equal content
                if (!a.equals(b) && a.isDeepEqualTo(b)) {
                    if (a.duplicates == 0 && b.duplicates == 0) {
                        // "a" has duplicates: 
                        // Add only "a" and discard "b" for the rest of the loops.
                        uniqueResults.add(a);
                    }
                    // count the number of duplicates
                    a.duplicates = a.duplicates + 1;
                }
            }
            // "a" has no duplicates, add it.
            if (a.duplicates == 0 && !uniqueResults.contains(a)) {
                uniqueResults.add(a);
            }
        }
        return uniqueResults;
}
```

It works so far - I don't see any edge cases where this would wrongly (not) remove.

It's also better than using **version 2** (with its `removableItems()`-list) as this is more performant (especially for huge lists) because we do not use `remove` or `removAll`, we only add items (which has O(1)).

Comment: Does removal from `all` ever takes place here??  If the number of duplicates is incremented how it should become 0 ?  Also, _why_ remove an element at index `i` (that is `a`)?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Thanks for helping. I edited my solution and this solution works and is the best so far. I would be glad if you can find a better solution or at least have suggestions to improve **version 4**.

Comment: There’s a fundamental problem with the software design when `!a.equals(b) && a.isDeepEqualTo(b)` can ever be true. The logic by which two objects can be “deep equal” but “not equal” at the same time will cause problems, sooner or later.

Comment: @Holger there is a difference between identically and equality. If I would use `equal()/hashCode()`, then I cannot distinguish between two different instances having the same content. Maybe the word `deepEqualTo()` is a little wrong, but what is meant here, is: "Compare two different instances and return `true` if the content (but not the instances) are equal to each other."

Comment: When you mean “the same instance”, you should use `==` which makes it obvious to the reader. “*Compare two different instances and return true if the content (but not the instances) are equal to each other*” is precisely the contract of `equals` (which, of course, has to be overridden for your own classes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use **CopyOnWriteArrayList** which support concurrent modification

```
List < String > myList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList < String > ();
    myList.add("1");
    myList.add("2");
    myList.add("3");
    myList.add("4");
    myList.add("5");
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("List value: " + myList.get(i));
      if (myList.get(i).equals("3")) {
        myList.remove(i);
        i--;
        myList.add("6");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("List Size:" + myList.size());
```

Comment: This is not a performant solution: CopyOnWriteArrayList copies all the elements into the new internal copy. So it would behave similar than using my *version2*